# How to download an open source project (like Spring) in github

Tags: spring, git, github

I wanted to download spring source from 
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework
I have installed Git in my local Windows Vista Machine. How to download and setup in eclipse project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [readme](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework#building-from-source) in the spring-framework repository for how to build the project and import it into eclipse.

If you use the [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) plugin for eclipse, you should be able to clone the spring-framework repository from within eclipse and have it setup as a new project.

Answer (score 1):

Either download it directly as a zip file from https://nodeload.github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/zipball/master or use `git clone` via the command line (`git clone git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework.git`).

Comment: Where is this location mentioned https://nodeload.github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/zipball/master
Also where we can find this zip location for other open source projects that are hosted in github?